# Xamarin MVVMCross : Register singleton of a class with more than one interfaces

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have a class implementation and 2 interfaces -

```
Public Interface IVehicle 
{
  void SelectVehicle(...);
}

Public Interface IDestination 
{
  void DistanceToDestination(...);
}

Public Class Travel : IVehicle, IDestination 
{

}
```

Because I am using `MVVMCross`, I know how to register for a singleton and resolve it like this -

Register - `Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton<IVehicle>(new Travel());`

Resove - `Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IVehicle>();`

Is there a way to register a single instance of class `Travel` with both the interfaces in MVVMCross?
something like this-
`Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton<IVehicle, IDestination>(new Travel());`

and way to resolve that single instance of `Travel` with both interfaces?
something like -

`var travel = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IVehicle, IDestination>();`
and use `travel` like `travel.DistanceToDestination(...);`

Comment: You posted how in theory you would register this, post how (in theory) how you want to resolve.

Comment: @mxmissile -  I am not really sure how to resolve it. I could write 2 separate resolve statements for both the interfaces, but that's not what is expected. Need to get a single instance of class `Travel` Still gave it a try, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of instantiating on each Register, just use the same instance:

```
var travel = new Travel();
Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton<IVehicle>(travel);
Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton<IDestination>(travel);
```

Then resolve as expected:

```
var travel = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IVehicle>();
```

or

```
var travel = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IDestination>();
```

Comment: I’ll try this. But then resolving with interface “IVehicle” will let me access methods of interface “IDestination” ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on the container [mvvmcross] uses. More than likely you will have to unbox like this:  `var travel = (Travel) Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IDestination>();`